# Vue Router not working once production is built

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

My Vue project works correctly when I build it using dev. However, once I run `npm run build` and move the files in dist to my webserver, Vue Router doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've tried removing history mode, but this didn't work.

Vue Router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Router)

const router =  new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/donate',
      name: 'donate',
      component: () => import('./views/Donate.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/guildselector',
      name: 'guildselector',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      component: () => import('./views/Guildselector.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/guild/:id',
      name: 'guild',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        requiresAdmin: true
      },
      component: () => import('./views/Guildpanel.vue')
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

`MyWebsite.com/guildselecto`r should show the `Guildselector` component for example, however I get a

```
Not Found The requested URL /guildselector was not found on this server.
```

Only the donate page and landing page work.

Comment: Does it also work if you copy the dev deployed files over to your webserver?

Comment: Yep. Just the production build that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very common problem; please read [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) in detail about how to configure your web server to host the files correctly.

> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access `http://oursite.com/user/id` directly in their browser.

Simple solution is just comment this line:

```
mode: 'history',
```

Comment: My Apache server has the exact same configuration as the one in that article. I'm not sure what else i'm supposed to do.

Comment: The Vue Router docs give you a chunk of Apache config, but don't tell you where to put it.  I first tried adding a file in the Apache conf.d directory, but that didn't work. Then I made a .htaccess file in the web root. It still had no effect. Turns out that you need to look for the `AllowOverride` directive in the httpd.conf file and set it to something other than "None".

Comment: The mod_rewrite example from https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations wasn't working for me. But FallbackResource was doing the trick. I just created a .htaccess file with only a a single line: FallbackResource index.html and placing it in the same folder as my index.html. That fixed it.