# Vue.js routes send to 404 on refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have made routes, if click on link in website it works as it should. But when you on that page (for example /aboutUs) and refresh it or simply copy url, paste it and hit Enter it shows Page not found. How to fix it? Run out of ideas, can't find answer that works anywhere

main.js below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.prototype.$careerEmpty = false;

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode:'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition){
        if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash}
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return {x:0, y:0}
        }
    },
    routes
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

routes.js below:

```js
import firstPage from "@/components/Pages/firstPage";
import aboutUsPage from "@/components/Pages/aboutUsPage";
import pageNotFound from "@/components/pageNotFound";

const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: firstPage},
    {path: '/aboutUs', component: aboutUsPage},
    {path: '/404', component: pageNotFound},
    {path: '*', redirect: '/404'},
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853332/734040).

Comment: How are you hosting your site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue router history mode.
[Check here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Vue.use(Router, {
  mode: 'history'
});